# Fetching values from the DropDownlist on PostBack inside Repeater Control in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, repeater, html-select

I have a `Repeater Control` on one of my asp.net page, i have some labels and one `dropdownlist` in the repeater control. Default contents are filled in the label and dropdownlist from the `Item_Bound` event. Now i want to achieve below:

- When user selects another item from the dropdownlist, the labels should be updated accordingly.

My Problem here is, as my default content is coming from the `item_bound`, it always over-rides the content from the dropdownlist, but if i place the `!IsPostBack` condition inside Item_Bound event, then on selecting dropdownlist nothing happens.

I have used OnSelectedIndexChange event, and just providing the Response.Write inside the event, but as the DropDownlist values overrides itself, i don't get anything on the response.

Can anyone help me with the logic about how shall i tackle this.

---

**Updated Question:**

Ok now i am able to fetch the results in the repeater label with the selectedItems from dropdown, but now my problem is i have binded multiple results inside repeater, i.e. each dropdowns per row, but when i select items from another row, it still assumes the value of the first row. Here is my code for reference:

```
protected void drpQuantity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //DropDown inside repeater control.
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptLatestProducts.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            HiddenField hd = item.FindControl("hdProductId") as HiddenField;
            DropDownList drp = item.FindControl("drpQuantity") as DropDownList;
            Label mrp = item.FindControl("lblMRP") as Label;
            Label ourPrice = item.FindControl("lblOurPrice") as Label;
            Label discount = item.FindControl("lblDiscount") as Label;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updPriceByUnits, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + hd.Value + "')", true); //Always returns product id of the first row.
            objPackage.ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(hd.Value);
            objPackage.TownId = objPackage.DefaultTown;
            int discountPercent = Convert.ToInt32(objPackage.GetProductPackages().Select("unit=" + drp.SelectedValue + " and productid=" + hd.Value)[0]["Discount"].ToString());
            mrp.Text = "<span class='rupee' style='font-size:14px;'>Rs</span>" + objPackage.GetProductPackages().Select("unit=" + drp.SelectedValue + " and productid=" + hd.Value)[0]["MRP"].ToString();
            ourPrice.Text = "<span class='rupee' style='font-size:14px;'>Rs</span>" + objPackage.GetProductPackages().Select("unit=" + drp.SelectedValue + " and productid=" + hd.Value)[0]["Price"].ToString();
            mrp.Visible = (mrp.Text != ourPrice.Text);
            if (discountPercent > 0)
            {
                discount.Visible = true;
                discount.Text = objPackage.GetProductPackages().Select("unit=" + drp.SelectedValue + " and productid=" + hd.Value)[0]["Discount"].ToString() + "% OFF";
            }
            else
            {
                discount.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are putting the `!Page.IsPostBack` around the wrong bit of code.

You need to put this around your `DataBind` code. So;

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
    this.myRepeater.DataSource = [yourdatasource];
    this.myRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

This way your `DropDownList` controls are not rebound.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Abbas - "!IsPostBack condition inside Item_Bound event" Me - "Sounds like you are putting the !Page.IsPostBack around the wrong bit of code"